# Reverb sort of airy synth note

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer, synthesis, replication

trying to make this sound that you hear in this track starting at 1:28 and you hear it throughout the entirety of the track.  Ive tried alot of things, using triangle waves or pulse waves,  two oscillators,  .  It seems like there is some sort of wobble like an lfo on the pitch or cuttoff or vibrato.  Ive tried also doing some tremelo.  There is obviously alot of reverb on it as well.  Cant seem to get it right.  It seems dissonant as well, tried to pitch two oscilators away from eachother by a semitone but doesnt seem to be working either

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the waveform - some sort of smoothed saw I guess.

As for the effect: Try with a delay going into an overdrive/distortion. The actual delay need to kick in a little hotter than the dry sound. Top it all with a little hall.

Here is that distorted delay effect (I know it is way more harsh here, but I think the chain is probably what you're after .. about 15 secs in):

Comment: Ive tried what you suggessted, however Im not getting that sort of of sound,  The delay sort of seems right but I can't get the note to sound correct when being played.  Like it seems like the filter settings are off or maybe Im not doing something write to get that vibrato sort of sound

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a triangle/sawtooth wave with a lowpass filter that is halfway opened, so it won't sound harsh or sharp. There might be an envelope on the filter to make it stab more (fast attack and decay around 100 - 300ms). Also I think you need a slight ring modulation or distortion on the sound to make sound more mechanical. The delay is routed before the reverb so every delay echo will have reverb. It's quite vague but that's how I think the sound might be designed.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but i only hear a delay-ed note(saw/triangle style) maybe some attack cut but nothing special, maybe it's the synth to some soft chorus to soft reverb to delay... but it's the context that makes it weird and airy .. once you have a mix like this with all the pumping factors and undertone style harmony a sound like that can cut the mix easily cause it's the hook for some time. but it's a rather simple sound... the nice thing about it is that it has a sort of combing effect like a honkyness which could've been produced by EQ or distorting of some sort.  But the sound dies awfully just a delay fading away... pretty simple stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I am hearing:

Filter:
On the tone itself, it starts with relatively few overtones, and opens out slightly during the entire life of the note. Oh-to-ah, sort of. If it is FM, the modulation index is what is growing slightly (via its envelope).

Tremolo:
It is fast (around 10Hz maybe a bit faster) and only affects the volume, not the filter or fundamental frequency. Also it is tied to the starting note as a trigger, not just vibrating freely. And it is of a high enough amplitude that it effectively sends the volume back to 0 and up, repeatedly, so the note sounds like it is retriggering. I'd try a sine on the tremolo wave, but it could be a triangle.

Envelope:
It seems to me that after the strong initial attack, there is a second stage where the volume continues to grow a small amount for almost a second, then tapers to silence. However, that sense of growth could be coming from the filter that is opening slowly.

The note on the right track (minor third above the left includes the first pitch as a two-note interval) is released more quickly, and the release envelope is clearly faster than the slow decay when the note is held (left side).

At first I thought it was an echo effect but decided it isn't for two reasons:
1) one doesn't usually route an echo output to a filter that is triggered
2) there are two different release profiles, so the echo would have to have different settings for the two notes.

Another thing to consider, the tremolo could be accomplished by a multistage envelope that can loop. I've seen very complex envelopes in FM8.

I don't think it is caused by beating tones. If it were, the two tones would have to be offset by 10Hz or a little more. I'm not hearing any distortion effects.